# How do I define nonfix operators in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, sml

In SML the "nonfix" operator can be used like:

```
datatype Proposition = Not_ of Proposition 

nonfix ~:
val ~: = Not_
```

In Haskell it would be like:

```
data Proposition = Not_ Proposition 

nonfix ~
(~) = Not_
```

But I didn't find an equivalent to "nonfix" in Haskell.

Comment: There are no unary operators in Haskell, except the unary `-` to negate a value.

Comment: I want to represent a logical proposition similar to this: `p ==> q  <=>  ¬ p /\ q`  but I need to represent the **negation sign**

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Unary_operator. Unary `-` is basically a special case handled by the parser, rather than just being the lone extant member of a class of possible unary operators.

Comment: You can cheat by using a symbol like `ᓕ U+14D5 CANADIAN SYLLABICS LI` or  `へ U+3078 HIRAGANA LETTER HE`, which can simply be used like any letter as a function name.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196237/how-do-i-define-a-postfix-operator-in-haskell regarding *postfix* unary operators.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Perhaps CANADIAN SYLLABICS LE (ᓓ) or HEBREW LETTER WIDE RESH (ﬧ) would also be good choices. For folks that don't know of it, [shapecatcher](https://shapecatcher.com) is a great resource here.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't find an equivalent because there isn't one. Make a different plan. Options include a non-embedded DSL; quasiquoters; using postfix instead of prefix; using a non-operator name (such as `not` or `(!)`); using CPP or another preprocessor.